# How do I use a regular expression to select the middle range of two nearest identical words?

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to select text between 2 identical and NEAREST words. For example:

```py
text = "WORD abc WORD def WORD ghi WORD"
```

How can I get [" abc ", " def ", " ghi "] instead of [" abc WORD def WORD ghi "]?

Comment: Try split by ``WORD`` like this, ``text.split("WORD")``

Comment: do you know what is the identical word or does it change all the time

Comment: Oh, yes! I was stuck in regular expression -- I forget I can use split(). The word won't change.  The split() does work!